# Javascript click counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>counter </TITLE>
</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">

var clicks = 0;
function linkClick(){
document.getElementById('clicked').value = ++clicks;
}
document.write('<a href="#" onclick="linkClick()">Add</a>');
</script>

<input id="clicked" size="3" onfocus="this.blur();" value="0" >
<script type="text/javascript">
function linkClick1(){
document.getElementById('clicked').value = --clicks;
}
document.write('<a href="#" onclick="linkClick1()">Subtract</a>');
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This on adds and subtracts depending on how many times its clicked i want the value not to go below 0 how to do it??

Comment: I've counted 7 bad practices in your code.

Comment: That's not a particularly helpful comment.  Maybe you could offer suggestions instead of smugly mocking?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer I've done that countless times. When I provide suggestions, my comments are mostly ignored. The few times OP responded, it was to tell me that my suggestions are "not relevant", and that I should not be bothering him with that.

Comment: Can You Please tell me what bad practices are in the code?? @Šime Vidas

Comment: @user2761593 1. Minimize the use of global variables in JavaScript. (There are 3 global variables in your code above.) 2. The `document.write` calls are senseless. Those are static HTML strings. Just place them in your HTML source directly. 3. You're querying the DOM in the "click" event handler. Better: query the DOM once on page init., and use that reference in the click handler. 4. The DOCTYPE is missing. 5. You're mixing uppercase and lowercase tag names in your HTML code. Use lowercase exclusively. 6. You're using on* event attributes. Bind event handlers dynamically in JavaScript.

Comment: @user2761593 Nr. 7 was the `type` attribute on `<script>` elements, but that's not a bad practice. It's just something you don't need to write.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
document.getElementById('clicked').value = ++clicks;
```

on:

```
document.getElementById('clicked').value = clicks >= 0? --clicks : clicks;
```

This might work, if it doesn't add a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function linkClick1(){
    if (clicks > 0) {
       document.getElementById('clicked').value = --clicks;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looking up a value inside a DOM-element while you still have that value available in `clicks`

Answer (score 0):

This is a more practical:

```
function linkClick1(){
    if (clicks > 0) {
       document.getElementById('clicked').value = --clicks;
    }
}
```